# Join Two Queries Into Columns in a Table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need help revising the query below. I'm trying to create a table like this:

```
| Jan 2014 | Feb 2014 |
|   7.5    |    8     |
```

But I end up getting this:

```
| Jan 2014 |
|   7.5    |
|     8    |
```

Is there a way to join these two (possibly more) queries into columns instead of rows? I'm using MS Access by the way. Thank you in advance.

My Current Query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT AVG([Length of Service in Years including Partial Year]) AS Jan2014 
 FROM [January 2014 HC] AS A) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT AVG([Length of Service in Years including Partial Year]) AS Feb2014 
 FROM [February 2014 HC] AS B)
```

Thanks NoDisplayName for the answer, I think I got it!

EDIT:

```
 SELECT * FROM
 (SELECT AVG([Length of Service in Years including Partial Year])
 FROM [January 2014 HC] AS A) AS Jan2014, 
 (SELECT AVG([Length of Service in Years including Partial Year]) 
 FROM [February 2014 HC] AS B) AS Feb2014
```

Answer (score 3):

Since both the queries going to return only one row you can do this.

```
select 
(SELECT AVG([Length of Service in Years including Partial Year]) 
 FROM [January 2014 HC]) AS Jan2014 , 
(SELECT AVG([Length of Service in Years including Partial Year]) 
 FROM [February 2014 HC]) AS Feb2014
```

Comment: I think I got it! I changed your answer a bit to make it work in access. I added '* FROM' after the first select and it worked. Thanks so much for the help!